# Angularjs decoupling backend models from controller

Tags: angularjs, mvvm

I am building a CRUD application using angularjs. Currently, I am using the json models returned from the back-end directly in my controllers. These models have a 3-4 level deep hierarchy. So my controller code looks like

```
$scope.prop1  = object1.object2.object3 
...
```

I am wondering whether I should decouple my controllers from these back-end models. So instead of using the model objects directly, create new (flattened) models and then use them in the controller. Is that a recommended practice?
What are the advantages / disadvantages of this ?

Comment: This is a good approach, but I would do it in the back-end. I would just send to the front-end a flattened object (like a DTO). Doing that, I can save some bytes when sending a response back to the client and also I would be improving the security, because I wouldn't be sending sensitive data that the client doesn't need.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to check domain of the object you're passing from backend. Do `object1` really *contain* `object2`? Are those objects connected or it is just handy to return?

Speaking about AngularJS - there is no any difference. You can `$watch('object1.object2.object3')` with mostly same performance impact as `$watch('object3')`. There will be no any error if `object2` will not contain `object3`. There will be a very small difference, as `$parse` will parse your expression to AST, and evaluating it will take little bit longer to traverse to third object. But this difference would be so small, so it would be extremely hard to notice.

So I would advice not to "flatten" everything or "normalise" into strict hierarchy, but try to figure our real relations between objects. Even if on start you won't see any difference, later it will pay back you with much higher maintainability rate.